# indexOf(), arrayList issue java

Tags: java, arraylist, indexof

Hello once again everyone,

I am currently working on a Java program that download a file, read it and copy its data in different arrayList. Then I simply want to get the index of some data, with the "indexOf()".

**There is my main with no problem :**

```
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import yhhFin.StockDownloader;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.io.*;
public class YhhFin {

   public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); //declaration du Scanner
        String track = "AAPL"; 

        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd");
        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
        int moisAJD = localDate.getMonthValue();
        int anneeAJD = localDate.getYear();
        int jourAJD =localDate.getDayOfMonth();
        GregorianCalendar end = new GregorianCalendar ( anneeAJD, moisAJD, jourAJD);
        GregorianCalendar start = new GregorianCalendar(2011, 11, 11);
        StockDownloader test  = new StockDownloader(track, start, end);

    System.out.println("Quel prix?");
      double prix = sc.nextDouble();
      StockDownloader tro = new  StockDownloader(prix) ;
      }
  }
```

**Then my other class that contain the method StockDownloader(prix) => problem**

```
package yhhFin;

public class StockDownloader
{


public static final int DATE = 0;
public static final int OPEN = 1;
public static final int HIGH = 2;
public static final int LOW = 3;
public static final int CLOSE = 4;
public static final int VOLUME = 5;
public static final int ADJCLOSE = 6;

private ArrayList<GregorianCalendar> dates;
private ArrayList<Double> open;
private ArrayList<Double> high;
private ArrayList<Double> low;
private ArrayList<Double> close;
private ArrayList<Integer> volume;
private ArrayList<Double> adjclose;


public StockDownloader (String symbol, GregorianCalendar start, GregorianCalendar end)
{
    dates= new ArrayList<GregorianCalendar>();
    open= new ArrayList<Double>();
    high= new ArrayList<Double>();
    low= new ArrayList<Double>();
    close= new ArrayList<Double>();
    volume= new ArrayList<Integer>();
    adjclose= new ArrayList<Double>();

   // http://chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=IBM&a=0&b=2&c=1962&d=3&e=12&f=2017&g=d&ignore=.csv

   String url = "http://chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s="+symbol+"&a="+start.get(Calendar.MONTH)+
           "&b="+ start.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+
           "&c="+start.get(Calendar.YEAR)+
           "&d="+end.get(Calendar.MONTH)+
           "&e="+end.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+
           "&f="+end.get(Calendar.YEAR)+
           "&g=d&ignore=.csv";



   try
   {
       URL yhoofin = new URL (url);
       URLConnection data = yhoofin.openConnection();
       Scanner input = new Scanner(data.getInputStream());
       if(input.hasNext())  //skip header
           input.nextLine();

       while(input.hasNextLine())
       {   
            String line = input.nextLine();

            String st[]=line.split(",");



           for(int i = 0; i < st.length; i++)
           {
               DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
               Date date = df.parse(st[0]);
               Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
               cal.setTime(date);
               dates.add((GregorianCalendar) cal);

                double valOpen = Double.parseDouble(st[1]);
                open.add(valOpen);
                //System.out.println(open.get(i));
                double valHigh = Double.parseDouble(st[2]);
                high.add(valHigh);

                double valLow = Double.parseDouble(st[3]);
                low.add(valLow);

                double valClose = Double.parseDouble(st[4]);
                close.add(valClose);

                int valvolume = Integer.parseInt(st[5]);
                volume.add(valvolume);

                double adjClose = Double.parseDouble(st[6]);
                adjclose.add(adjClose);
            }

         }
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
       System.err.println(e);
   }
}

//the important method
public   StockDownloader (double price) {
   int index;
    index= open.indexOf(price);//the code crash when reaching this line
    System.out.println("INDEX : " +index);
}
}
```

I tried to be as explicit as I could, It is not a scope issue as the array are declare in the class so I can access them.

Could you please enlighten me as I struggle on this problem for a couple days now.

Thank you so much.

Vik55

PS: I did some research, I saw many post similar to this one but could not solve my problem, apparently I might have a declaration issue, I don't really get it .

Comment: What happens when you compile and run your program? Do you get any errors? If so, what are they?

Comment: p.s. You should create a class `Stock` which stores the `high`, `low`, `close`, etc. values. Then you can create a single `ArrayList<Stock>` instead of so many parallel lists.

Comment: The error : 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at yhhFin.StockDownloader.<init>(StockDownloader.java:131)
 at yhhfin.YhhFin.main(YhhFin.java:71)

Comment: So what is the error? And what code causes it?

Comment: Java programs very rarely just "crash". In 99.9999% of the cases, they terminate with a very specific exception and a quite verbose stack trace.  Perhaps you can't make sense of the exception error message, so you consider it as noise, so you omit posting it in your question, but trust me, the exception error message is by far the most important piece of information.  Post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two constructors.  One initializes the arraylists, the other one does not.  Of course, all of your arraylists are NULL in the constructor which does not initialize them, so the moment it tries to access one of them, it fails with a null pointer exception.

This is a very basic mistake for which all decent compilers give warnings. So:

1. Learn how to enable warnings in your development environment.
2. Enable all warnings.
3. ***Pay attention to them.***

Comment: I'm really ashamed of my ignorance right now. I need more background in java!! 
Thank you for your patience and your quick answer!!

Comment: Try this very useful syntax: `private ArrayList<Double> open = new ArrayList<Double>();`

Comment: Of course this won't do you any good, because your arraylist will always be empty in your second constructor.  That's because it should not be a constructor, it should be a method.  So, go back to the books, and study to learn the difference between ***a constructor*** and ***a method***.

Comment: Understood, I think I have an idea of how doing this. But is there a simple way to access an arrayList filled in a different constructor?

Comment: It is possible, with `this(...)`, but it won't help you in this case, because each time you do `new StockDownloader( ... )` you get a different object.  So, you construct one object with the constructor that fills it in, and then you construct another object with the constructor that searches it.  The object that you construct with the searching constructor will always be empty.  You need to start using methods instead of constructors.

Comment: So I could use a method, give this method the data that I am looking for, and it will return the index? And then create another method that will receive the index and get me back the date? Is that what you are trying to explain me?

Comment: Yes, or you could use a constructor to construct an empty object, a method to fill in the object, and another method to search through the filled-in object.

Answer (score 0):

```
    index= open.indexOf(price);//the code crash when reaching this line
```

it crashes because open points to null, aka it's not initialized.
You should add

```
    open= new ArrayList<Double>();
```

as you did for the other constructor.

Comment: Indeed this solve my error. As I told to Mike Nakis, I really need to work on my Java . Thanks for you quick answer and your patience